# Typo3 extension are automatically deactivated

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x

i have a running Typo3 7.6.11 installation on my webhoster.

I noticed that the extensions "powermail" and "dynamic content elements" get somehow automatically deactivated over night.

I can activate them in the Backend via Extensions, but the next morning they are both deactivated again.

Any ideas on that?

Answer (score 1):

What cron-jobs and scheduler-tasks are configured? at what time?

the next I would do is writing a cronjob, which logs every 5 minutes the md5-hash of your PackageStates.php into a file. if the file is modified the hash should change and you nearly know the time the change occurs. compare to cron-jobs/ scheduler-tasks running at that time.

Answer (score 0):

Check the system log of your installation, if someone else did not login during night into your system. If no-one did, contact your webhoster, since someone has is changing your files directly on the system, so they should be able to figure out if it is some security issue or maybe some faulty backup procedures.

Comment: No other logins
According to the webhoster no backup procedure

Answer (score 0):

In the Install-Tool there is an option to do a check for broken extensions and after the check the "broken extensions" are deinstalled automatically. May be you have a task running in the scheduler that does this routine?

Normally after a system update some of the extensions are broken because they use a deprecated api and also have to be updated, so you should also check if there is an update for these extensions.

Comment: When i run broken extensions, it says everything is alright (and the extensions are still activated)

No update for those extensions available

Answer (score 0):

do you have an automatic deployment?
does this deployment know that these extensions needs to be active?

Comment: No automatic deployment

Answer (score 0):

Please check permission of typo3conf/PackageStates.php file, Is there any cron-job that automatic deactivate extensions.
If not then try to overwrite extensions with new vesrion.